# JPA2 with MySQL backend: MyISAM or InnoDB

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, transactions, jpa-2.0

Obviously, there is plenty out there about MyISAM vs InnoDB engine selection, but I couldn't find anything specific to JPA2.

Is it possible to use a MyISAM engine together with java persistence API, and still have transaction support? Or does it rely on the RDBMS to provide rollback / commit functionality?

Are there other (non-obvious) factors that need to be considered? What about `@Cascade`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this posting](http://www.insaneprogramming.be/?p=200), which makes a pretty good case for using transactional RDBMS backends.

I managed to reproduce the behaviour:

- Create an entity
- Within the transaction, throw an Exception

With MyISAM, the entity will remain created. With InnoDB, the entity is created, but then rolled back. So even though I haven't been able to find something official, I am convinced that **a transactional backend is required** if one expects container-provided transactions to work.